# Enabling PDF preview in Dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, kde, pdf, dolphin

Hϵllo everyone. I have installed KDE on my Ubuntu 11.10 install. It's working nicely except for a couple of gripes with Dolphin file manager.

1. It seems much slower than other file browsers. Any particular reasons for this? Any way how I could speed it up?
2. I want to enable PDF preview for Dolphin. On googling a bit, I found a page that suggested following command:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install kdegraphics-strigi-plugins
   ```

   The preview doesn't work for me even after I ran the above command. How do I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/702389/pdf-thumbnails-are-missing-in-dolphin

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Slower than other file browsers ?**

What other ? Konqueror ? Krusader ?

The Dolphin is the default KDE file manager but you don't need to use it. System Settings > Default Applications > File Manager.

**Thunbnails ?**

Package: kdegraphics-thumbnailers

```
:~$ apt-cache show kdegraphics-thumbnailers
Description: graphics file format thumbnailers for KDE SC
 These plugins allow KDE software to create thumbnails for several
 advanced graphic file formats (PS, RAW).
Homepage: http://www.kde.org/
```

Commandline install:

```
sudo apt-get install kdegraphics-thumbnailers
```

Dolphin > Settings > Configure Dolphin > General > Previews: Show previews for PostScript, PDF and DVI Files

You may need to rise the "Do not create previews for" limit !

[image]

**--- EDIT ----**

Comment:

> Slower than Nautilus, its GNOME brother.

I have not used the Nautilus but the developer /1/, /2/ is promising improved performance with the KDE 4.8 & Dolphin 2.0.

Comment:

> ...Though I don't get why I have to hit the "preview" button on
>   toolbar for every directory I enter in. How can I make it the default
>   behavior?

One way: Dolphin > View > Adjust View Properties. Press the F1 key, when the Dolphin is active, to get the Dolphin Handbook.

Another way /3/: Open the Dolphin in the ~/.kde/share/apps/dolphin/view_properties/global/   (*1) and turn the Icons/Details/Columns/Preview/... on/off. The settings are saved to the ~/.kde/share/apps/dolphin/view_properties/global/.directory file and used as the global defaults - IF the local folder does not have own .directory file with the overriding settings.

KDE .directory file:

The .directory file is a KDE folder view properties file. It contains the folder viewing settings for a directory in KDE. It includes settings such as icon positions and view mode (icon, list, etc.). Automatically created when the view settings of a folder are modified. Hidden by default.

(*1) If the ~/.kde/share/apps/dolphin/view_properties/global/ directory does not exist, you could make it.

More of the Dolphin: KDE UserBase /4/ and the Dolphin KDE Home /5/.

**Links**

1. http://ppenz.blogspot.com/
2. http://ppenz.blogspot.com/2011/08/introducing-dolphin-20.html
3. http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?55954-Solved-Dolphin-settings&s=3b900a05916fdf62051c6acedb4d9e7c
4. http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin
5. http://dolphin.kde.org/index.html

Comment: Slower than Nautilus, its GNOME brother.

Comment: I have the `kdegraphics-thumbnailers` installed, and I followed the steps you have given. Still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oh yes, it works. Though I don't get why I have to hit the "preview" button on toolbar for every directory I enter in. How can I make it the default behavior?

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I followed your recommendation but still does not work, I could only get a preview of a few pdf files. But I have increased the size limitation for preview to make sure that all my files are smaller than that. I am using Kubuntu 16.10.

Comment: I am on Arch Linux and this solution (Commandline Install) worked perfectly for me. `two-thumbs up` !!!