# PDF thumbnails are missing in Dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, pdf, dolphin, thumbnails, kde5

I can't find out how to enable Pdf previews in Dolphin 15.08.2, is it possible in this new version?

`kdegraphics-thumbnailers` is installed and uptodate

Comment: kdegraphics-thumbnailers is installed and uptodate

Comment: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=351913

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by [user26687](https://askubuntu.com/users/26687/user26687) the solution mentioned in the [bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=351913) seems to solve the problem:

1. install the needed thumbnailers
2. make a symbolic link to the installed thumbnailers in the qt5 plugins folder, run:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plugins/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/
   ```

Replace `x86_64-linux-gnu` with `i386-linux-gnu` for 32bit.

Note: the problem still exists in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS xenial xerus.

The bug is also known in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdegraphics-thumbnailers/+bug/1574049).